# ng-repeat with image is not displaying?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have stored icons in cloudinary. here i have used ng-repeat to list the stores everything working find but icons not displaying i have enclosed my html and controller code .i have got icons like this http://res.cloudinary.com/*******/icon1.png,http://res.cloudinary.com/icon2.png,http://res.cloudinary.com/icon3.png

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('TestController', ['$scope','$filter','$http',
      function($scope, $filter,$http) {
        
         $http.get('****').success(function(data, dealers, response) {
           
           $scope.dealers = data;
           console.log(data.icons);
           
           });
      
  }]);
//console i am getting icons like this
"http://res.cloudinary.com/*******/icon1.png,http://res.cloudinary.com/icon2.png,http://res.cloudinary.com/icon3.png"
```

```html
<div class="list card"  data-ng-repeat="dealer in dealers | filter:query ">
 <img ng-src="{{dealer.icons}}" ></img> 
</div>
```

Comment: what's the type of `dealer.icons`? Is it array or string?

Comment: string i am getting http://res.cloudinary.com/*******/icon1.png,http://res.cloudinary.com/icon2.png,http://res.cloudinary.com/icon3.png

Comment: yes. this string is not a valid URI. You should parse it as K K said in their answer.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned:

```
//console i am getting icons like this    "http://res.cloudinary.com/*******/icon1.png,http://res.cloudinary.com/icon2.png,http://res.cloudinary.com/icon3.png"
```

Its a string. And you cannot iterate on a string. You need to convert it into an array then iterate on it.

Use `split(",")` to convert the string to array. [Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Change this line:

```
$scope.dealers = data;
```

To:

```
$scope.dealers = data.icons.split(",");
```

**Side note:**

Img is a self closing tag. Correct it to:

```
<img src="" />
```

Comment: It means that you should have a data which can be iterated. A string cannot be iterated because it doesn't have any sub-items. An array, object has sub items and hence can be iterated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert data.icons into an array first:

```
$scope.dealers = data.icons.split(',');
```

and then:

```
<div class="list card" data-ng-repeat="dealer in dealers | filter:query">
  <img ng-src="dealer"/>
</div>
```